# How is print('\r') or print(' ') giving me the output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

We were asked to print the following output:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7
8 8 8
9 9 
10
```

I understand that it would require two loops so I tired this:

```
a = int(input())
i = a
f = 1
while i>0:
 for j in range(i):
      print(f,end=' ')
 f += 1
 i -= 1
 print('\r')
```

With this I am getting the desired output, but as soon as I remove the last line of print('\r') the output becomes something like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6       6 6 6 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 10
```

The desired output also comes out when I used print(' ') instead of print('\r'), I don't understand why this is happening?

Ps: I am a noob coder, starting my freshman year, so please go easy on me, if the formatting is not up to the mark, or the code looks bulky.

Comment: You need to do `print('\n')` as your last line.  `\r` puts the cursor back at column 1 but does not advance to the next line.  And you don't really need two counters there; you can do `for f in range(1,a+1):`.

Comment: @TimRoberts `print('\n')` would print two newlines due to `print()`'s nature of always printing a newline by default.

Comment: You are right.  `print('')` is the right answer.

Comment: in other some languages or script languages (most of old versions) ,in servers design for Windows OS  we use CRLF     \r\n      .. i do not know python so try yourself if this will change things      \r = carriage return   , \n= new line

Comment: Ok so print(' ') will automatically shift the cursor to the next line, but what I do not understand is that, why does the cursor automatically not go to the next line, after the print(f,end='') statement, why I need to add an extra print? @Felk do you mean that print() always prints a new blank line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not helping you so much but the following code produces the expected output:

```
a = 10
for i, j in enumerate(range(a, 0, -1), 1):
    print(*[i] * j)

# Output:
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1   # i=1, j=10
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2     # i=2, j=9
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3       # i=3, j=8
4 4 4 4 4 4 4         # i=4, j=7
5 5 5 5 5 5           # i=5, j=6
6 6 6 6 6             # i=6, j=5
7 7 7 7               # i=7, j=4
8 8 8                 # i=8, j=3
9 9                   # i=9, j=2
10                    # i=10, j=1
```

The two important parameters here are `sep` (when you print a list) and `end` as argument of `print`. Let's try to use it:

```
a = 10
for i, j in enumerate(range(a, 0, -1), 1):
    print(*[i] * j, sep='-', end='\n\n')

# Output:
1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1

2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2

3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3

4-4-4-4-4-4-4

5-5-5-5-5-5

6-6-6-6-6

7-7-7-7

8-8-8

9-9

10
```

**Update**

Step by step:

```
# i=3; j=8

>>> print([i])
[3]

>>> print([i] * j)
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]

# print takes an arbitrary number of positional arguments.
# So '*' unpack the list as positional arguments (like *args, **kwargs)
# Each one will be printed and separated by sep keyword (default is ' ')
>>> print(*[i] * j)
```

Comment: Came up with identical solution, so I upvoted yours :-)

Comment: I understand your code, but can you please explain *[i]?What task did you perform here??

Comment: I updated my answer. I expand the list into position arguments for `print` function. Check https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Answer (score 1):

To make it all easier and prevent errors, you can simply do this:

```
n = 10
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    txt = str(i) + " " # Generate the characters with space between
    print(txt * (n + 1 - i)) # Print the characters the inverse amount of times i.e. 1 10, 10 1
```

Where it generates the text which is simply the number + a space, then prints it out the opposite amount of times, (11 - current number), i.e. 1 ten times, 10 one time.

Comment: Ok yeah, I could have tried that string approach, I have been doing some tuple questions, so I forgot that the string outputs are displayed without the '' when printing without a tuple or a list.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using 2 or 4 spaces for indenting. Let's take a look:

```py
a = int(input())
i = a
f = 1
while i>0:
    for j in range(i):
        print(f,end=' ')
    f += 1
    i -= 1
    print('\r')
```

Notice the `print(f,end=' ')` within the inner loop. the `end=' '` bit is important because `print()` appends a trailing new line `\n` to every call by default. Using `end=' '` instead appends a space.

Now take a look at `print('\r')`. It does not specify `end=' '`, so it does still append a newline after each call to print. The fact that you additionally print a `\r` is inconsequential in this case. You could also just do `print()`.

Comment: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) is very clear on the matter, indentation is 4 spaces. (Using tabs is okay if working with code that is already using tabs.)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way :

```
rows = 10
b = 0

for i in range(rows, 0, -1):
    b += 1
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
    print(b, end=' ')
    print('\r')
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for multiple loops.

```
for i in range(1,11):
    # concatenate number + a space repeatedly, on the same line
    # yes, there is an extra space at the end, which you won't see ;-)
    print(f"{i} " * (11-i))
```

#### output:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 5 
6 6 6 6 6 
7 7 7 7 
8 8 8 
9 9 
10
```

#### As to what's happening with your code...

A basic Python `print` prints on a line, meaning that it *ends* with a line feed (which moves it to the next line).

So, if I take your word for it, you've done all the hard work of say the first line of 10 ones with spaces, when you are done at the following point.

```
#your code
 f += 1
 i -= 1
```

Now, so far you've avoided that line feed by changing the `end` parameter to print so that it *doesn't end with a newline*.  So you have:

`1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`

And still no line feed.  Great!

But if you now start printing `2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2` , it will just get added to... the end of the previous line, without line feed.

So to force a line feed, you *print anything you want, but without the `end` parameter being set, so that print now *ends* with the linefeed it uses by default.

Example:

```
#without line feed
print("1 " * 3, end=' ')
print("2 " * 2, end=' ')
```

#### output:

```
1 1 1  2 2
```

Lets try printing something, anything, without a `end = ' '`)

```
print("1 " * 3, end=' ')
#now add a line by a print that is NOT using `end = ' '`
print("!")
print("2 " * 2, end=' ')
```

output:

```
1 1 1  !
2 2
```

OK, so now we have a line feed after `!` so you jump to the next line when printing the 2s.  But you don't want to see anything after the 1s.

Simples, print anything that is invisible.

```
print("1 " * 3, end=' ')
#now add a line by a print, but using a non-visible character.
#or an empty string.  Tabs, spaces, etc... they will all work
print(" ")
print("2 " * 2, end=' ')
```

output:

```
1 1 1
2 2
```

This would also work:

```
print("1 " * 3, end=' ')
#we could also print a linefeed and end without one...
print("\n", end="")
print("2 " * 2, end=' ')
```